# pending publication on play console

Tags: android, google-play-console

I have published app at 2pm on thursday(17-10-2019) .It's not published yet.What would have been the issue.I want it to be done fast as we have planned for its release.

If there is any issue with the publish ,how will it be communicated to me?

Answer (score 16):

Please check this [thread](https://www.androidpolice.com/2019/09/03/google-play-expands-store-app-review/?amp), it's a common problem nowadays.

**Key point:**

- Google is now reviewing all apps and updates before they are published. (There was some confusion about whether updates are reviewed, but numerous developers confirmed they've seen their own updates delayed for multiple days.)
- All developers go through reviews, but established high-traffic developers will often get faster approvals. App updates are usually approved faster than new apps.
- There is no way to expedite (speed up) the review process.
- Updates can be scheduled, but scheduling the launch of new apps requires an awkward workaround.
- No notice was given to developers warning of a potential multi-day approval process until they attempt to publish.

> Google's current knowledge base article still claims this only happens
>   to "certain developer accounts" and goes on to recommend planning at
>   least three days for apps to be approved. Comments from developers
>   seem to indicate that they have seen turnaround in as little as a few
>   hours or up to several days. Notably, there is no visible warning in
>   the developer console about delays, it only appears after publishing.

**Note**: *For certain developer accounts, we’ll take more time to thoroughly review your app(s) to help better protect users. You’ll receive a notification on your app's Dashboard about how long this should take. We recommend that you adjust your planning to include a buffer period of at least three days between submitting your app and going live.*
— [Google Play Console help article](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6334282)

Answer (score 2):

The situation appears to have precipitated, most probably with the COVID situation. Many users are pending for 30 days.

There is a hot discussion here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/thread/35061212?hl=en

Following the official answer from the Google Developer Support Team:

> Thanks for contacting Google Play Developer Support.
> I understand you are concerned with the time being taken for your app to be processed for publishing on Google Play. Due to adjusted work schedules and a limited team we are operating in light of a precautionary health measure at this time, we are currently experiencing longer than usual review times. While the situation is currently evolving, app review times may fluctuate, and processing can take a few hours or up to 7 days or longer in exceptional cases, as it depends on the review time that your app is subject to.
> Consequently, It is unfortunate that the review process is unable to be expedited. Please note that submitting changes to your app while a review is already pending will mean the review period starts over, so we recommend you adjust your planning to account for this and avoid resubmitting, including updates submitted using the Google Play Developer API, changes to your store listing page, distribution to a new country/region, and binary releases.
> Plus, in order to distinguish the current status of your latest submission, an indication "Processing update" would be displayed on the Dashboard page in Play Console while your app is currently under the app review procedure. Conversely, if the review is completed and the submission is approved, the indication would become "All updates are live".
> We understand the inconvenience this may cause and thank you for your patience and understanding. For detailed information regarding extended review, please refer to the following blog:
> https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/04/google-play-updates-and-information.html

Answer (score 2):

1. If you want your new app published faster, you should publish as alpha before. Publishing as alpha is necessary for testing in App billing and no one will see your application on alpha except your testers. When it comes to publish on production (normal publishing everyone can see this version), you should just upgrade from alpha to production and that’s it. Your application will be live on 1 hour or less.
2. If your app has been delayed more than 7 days, we suggest you to contact Google Developer Support Team. Then, you will get a reply.
3. Though it is not recommended by Google, you can resubmit your app. In my experience, this method is helpful.
   Please refer to the following post of which I'm the author: https://seoasoorm.com/google-play-pending-publication/

Comment: You appear to be the author of the linked article. When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.